# Pass parameter to windows scheduled task

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

How do I pass parameters to a scheduled task?

Answer (score 4):

Add the parameters to the end of the Run textbox in Properties

Comment: What if the parameters are variable?

Comment: @BryceGuinta: What do you mean?

Comment: I only know what I want to pass into the task right before I call the task and the value changes each time

Comment: @BryceGuinta: Then you need to write a program or batch file to compute them.

Comment: Right, I'm calling schtasks in a batch file. However the only way ive figured out how to pass data from the batch file to the task is to store the bash variable into a known file path and then have the task script to read that file

Comment: @BryceGuinta: Why can't you make the task run a batch file that computes the data directly?

Comment: The calling batch file is a an event (post commit-hook) which shouldn't have blocking operations. Svn doesn't give me a choice of a task

Comment: @BryceGuinta: Then you can embed your parameter values directly in the command-line that you pass to `schtasks`.

Comment: That is my problem. `schtasks` doesn't have a way to pass arbitrary arguments to the task from the command-line.

Comment: That link is only for creating a task on the command-line. I would have to create a new task each time I wanted to run the script, which doesn't make much sense (might as well use a function).

It looks like there is no direct way to feed changing arguments into a task without creating a new task.